# How does offsetForTimes function internally work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

How does [offsetForTimes](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L2079) function internally work. Does it pull the offset based on the metadata info or it actually pulls the Kafka message to identify the offset of the given timestamp.

Can there be any scenario when the offset returned by [offsetForTimes](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java#L2079) method is missing on the broker/ Node?